# What is causing OpenSSL to segfault?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ssl, openssl

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x040010c2 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#1  0x06a14a0b in write () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#2  0x04154ae9 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#3  0x041518e4 in BIO_write () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#4  0x040781f1 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#5  0x040785ff in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#6  0x04078855 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#7  0x04075e28 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#8  0x0408d709 in SSL_write () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#9  0x0409c451 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#10 0x041518e4 in BIO_write () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#11 0x0814b10f in SSL_Connection_send (connection=0x9ffbbd0) 
...

(gdb) print *connection->bio
$1 = {method = 0x40ac800, callback = 0, cb_arg = 0x0, init = 1, shutdown = 1, flags = 0, retry_reason = 0, num = 0, ptr = 0xa27e768, next_bio = 0x7b84ad0, prev_bio = 0x0, references = 1, num_read = 904, 
  num_write = 2870, ex_data = {sk = 0x0, dummy = 774321733}}

(gdb) print *connection->ssl
$2 = {version = 769, type = 4096, method = 0x40aacc0, rbio = 0x7b84ad0, wbio = 0x7b84ad0, bbio = 0x0, rwstate = 2, in_handshake = 0, handshake_func = 0x40738f0, server = 0, new_session = 0, quiet_shutdown = 0, 
  shutdown = 0, state = 3, rstate = 240, init_buf = 0x0, init_msg = 0xf5838e4, init_num = 0, init_off = 0, 
  packet = 0xf848ebb "\027\003\001\001\330HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nCache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate\r\nContent-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8\r\nETag: \"cacca674ed49d64124f812372ad59561"..., packet_length = 0, s2 = 0x0, s3 = 0xf3ea410, d1 = 0x0, read_ahead = 0, msg_callback = 0, msg_callback_arg = 0x0, hit = 0, param = 0x99f82b8, cipher_list = 0x0, 
  cipher_list_by_id = 0x0, mac_flags = 0, enc_read_ctx = 0xace5438, read_hash = 0xabce1c8, expand = 0x0, enc_write_ctx = 0x9794468, write_hash = 0xc057018, compress = 0x0, cert = 0xe1f70d8, sid_ctx_length = 0, 
  sid_ctx = '\000' , session = 0x7d54760, generate_session_id = 0, verify_mode = 0, verify_callback = 0, info_callback = 0, error = 0, error_code = 0, psk_client_callback = 0, 
  psk_server_callback = 0, ctx = 0xae8ce30, debug = 0, verify_result = 20, ex_data = {sk = 0x0, dummy = 0}, client_CA = 0x0, references = 1, options = 4, mode = 4, max_cert_list = 102400, first_packet = 0, 
  client_version = 769, max_send_fragment = 16384, tlsext_debug_cb = 0, tlsext_debug_arg = 0x0, tlsext_hostname = 0x0, servername_done = 0, tlsext_status_type = -1, tlsext_status_expected = 0, 
  tlsext_ocsp_ids = 0x0, tlsext_ocsp_exts = 0x0, tlsext_ocsp_resp = 0x0, tlsext_ocsp_resplen = -1, tlsext_ticket_expected = 1, tlsext_ecpointformatlist_length = 3, tlsext_ecpointformatlist = 0xac40bc8 "", 
  tlsext_ellipticcurvelist_length = 50, tlsext_ellipticcurvelist = 0x7b20878 "", tlsext_opaque_prf_input = 0x0, tlsext_opaque_prf_input_len = 0, tlsext_session_ticket = 0x0, tls_session_ticket_ext_cb = 0, 
  tls_session_ticket_ext_cb_arg = 0x0, tls_session_secret_cb = 0, tls_session_secret_cb_arg = 0x0, initial_ctx = 0xae8ce30, next_proto_negotiated = 0x982fd50 "Groups.History", 
  next_proto_negotiated_len = 111 'o', srtp_profiles = 0x7373656d, srtp_profile = 0x2e656761, tlsext_heartbeat = 1953720648, tlsext_hb_pending = 0, tlsext_hb_seq = 424, renegotiate = 1232, srp_ctx = {
    SRP_cb_arg = 0x0, TLS_ext_srp_username_callback = 0x6f697463, SRP_verify_param_callback = 0x64695f6e, SRP_give_srp_client_pwd_callback = 0x4c4f202c, login = 0x72742e44 "", N = 0x498, g = 0x0, s = 0xa, 
    B = 0xfc0301, A = 0xfc03, a = 0x0, b = 0x0, v = 0x0, info = 0x0, strength = 0, srp_Mask = 0}}
```

I am trying to figure out why this is erroring. The error happens randomly when I make a request to a server (only on linux too). Could it be that the remote side has closed the connection (connection->bio->shutdown == 1)? Or is it a memory error (next_proto_negotiated = 0x982fd50 "Groups.History"...that doesnt look like a protocol, although valgrind didnt pick up any memory error).

Comment: Can you show your code? Are you doing any multi-threaded programming, accessing the socket on different threads at the same time?

Comment: @JohnKugelman while the code is multithreaded, the socket should only be accessed from a single thread. I will try and see if maybe thats not the case. As far as showing code, the error occurs on `BIO_write(connection->bio, &data[total_written], length-total_written);` and at the point of the error `total_written` is 0. Any code past that is client logic.

Comment: Make sure you're not writing to it on one thread and closing it on another. I've made that mistake before and seen crashes just like this. It took some annoying rearchitecting to get all the SSL calls on one thread. That's why multithreading came to mind.

Comment: @JohnKugelman it appears that you might be correct (this is a heisenbug so its hard for me to determine whether or not the problem was actually solved) but I found that my connection struct didnt change the state to closed on a call to ssl connection close. thanks!

Comment: One thing you might do here to make this more readable: build your own OpenSSL. But before `config` and `make all`, open `Configure`, find `linux-x86_64`, and add `-02 -g3` to `CFLAGS`. It should fix most of the `0x04154ae9 in ??`-type frames.

Comment: @chacham15: "while the code is multithreaded..." - did you install the static locks?

Comment: @noloader I installed both the dynlock functions as well as the static functions, and thanks for the tip. I'll try that next time this error pops up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you doing any multi-threaded programming, accessing the socket on different threads at the same time? If so, make sure you're not writing to it on one thread and closing it on another. I've made that mistake before and seen crashes just like this. It took some annoying rearchitecting to get all the SSL calls on one thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issues because of multi-threading, it might help to sleep for a second between two calls to SSL_shutdown(). The following article does exactly that even in a single threaded program.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtps5%2Fs5sple2.html

Answer (score 0):

I have seen openssl on Linux segfault if the server neglects to call `SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context` when setting up the TLS context.

A good indication that this is causing the crash is if a newer TLS client, such as Windows Server 2012, is trying to reconnect with TLS tickets. What you will see is every other connection attempt causing a segfault, as after a good connection, the client comes back for a second connection using a TLS ticket.

Even if you are not using TLS tickets or session caching, see if adding a call to `SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context` solves the issue.